# WC Add to cart with Ajax - Only first product is added

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WordPress 5.6.1 + WooCommerce 4.9.2

I created a function to add product into cart with Ajax.
My function is very specific as I create a new tailored product and then added to cart.

First I had issue to authorize this ajax call for non connected users.
This is corrected but now I have issue :

- First product is correctly added to cart
- Next products are not added to cart (but created correctly)

Can you have a look on my code?

1. I force Ajax Call otherwise not working for non connected users

> ```
> function forceAjaxCall(){
>   function forceit(){
>       if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='create_product_sdwc'):
>               do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
>               do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
>       endif;
>   }
>   add_action('wp_loaded', 'forceit');
> }
> ```

2. My ajax function

   ```
   function odc_create_product_sdwc() {  
    ob_start();
    global $woocommerce;
    $product = new WC_Product();
    $d = new DateTime();
    $product->set_props( array(
        'name'               => "Produit test",
        'featured'           => false,
        'catalog_visibility' => 'hidden',
        'description'        => "ma Description",
        'short_description'  => 'Transparence : ',
        'regular_price'      => 10,
        'sale_price'         => 10,
        [....]
    ) );

    $productId = $product->save();

    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $productId, 1 );
    error_log("passed_validation " . $passed_validation);

    $reponse = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productId, 1);
    error_log("added to cart : key " . $reponse);
    error_log("added to cart : ID " . $productId);
    do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $productId );

    wp_die();
   ```

   }

Comment: I noticed that if I remove wp_die() then the product is created 4 times.
I think my issue is about cache or ob_start, flush etc but can't find a solution..

Answer (score 0):

After hours or research I finally found the solution...
The add_to_cart was correct

The issue was with the non logged users and my function  forceAjaxCall()

Correct answer is :

```
function forceAjaxCall(){
    function forceit(){
        if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='create_product_sdwc'){
            do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
        };
    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'forceit'); // admin_init !!!!
}
```